# Missing drawables at runtime

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

Problem:

My App is missing resources at runtime.
One activity just get killed at startup. (error: color 0x2 could not get converted)
The other activity shows a screen with standard graphics instead of the included ones.

What I did before:

I'm still using Eclipse ADT and wanted to give Android Studio a try.
I already uninstall it to get rid of the runtime issue without success.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I think there is a general compiling error as there where no errors in this parts before.

Code 1:

```
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, android.R.anim.fade_in)
```

Stacktrace 1:

```
Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x21b "res/drawable/btn_default.xml" a=1 r=0x1080004}
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/btn_default.xml"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x21b "res/drawable/btn_default.xml" a=1 r=0x1080004}
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
at android.view.animation.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:246)
at android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation.<init>(AlphaAnimation.java:40)
at java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/btn_default.xml"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
at android.view.animation.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:246)
at android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation.<init>(AlphaAnimation.java:40)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:116)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:91)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:116)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:72)
...
```

Code 2 (MY_activity.java:47):

```
setContentView(R.layout.MY_activity);
```

Stacktrace 2:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app/my.app.activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3163)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3223)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:312)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
at my.app.MY_activity.onCreate(MY_activity.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
... 25 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:831)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:632)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:266)
... 28 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:640)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:579)
... 41 more
```

Comment: Could you show the stack trace?

Comment: and the code used to set the color?

Comment: rename `MY_activity.xml`to `my_activity.xml` (not following Android stds) . Are the rest of your xml correct?

Comment: @eduyayo I changed the activity name before posting it (in my real code it is conform to the Standards). And yes, the code worked already (until I installed Android Studio and tried to import it)!

Comment: Google is pushing the Studio but half of the new issues in StackOverflow have to do with it (just check and main page had 10 new issues). After commenting on what I saw wrong, just tell you: you rather be using Eclipse until that thing works properly.

Comment: I have this issue with Eclipse + ADT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the new material design like this:

```
Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar
```

The correct form (after including appcompat v7):

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```